# how to filter out correct words with spaces from a lxml data string using beatifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

hi guyz here i'm getting on string that contains lots of html data (in single string)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import bs4
url = "any randome url"
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
web_page=soup.get_text().strip()
print(web_page.lower())
```

and some of the words are coming in output like

`conditionstravel` for `conditions` & `travel`

`vaccinationstreatment` for `vaccination` & `treatment`

the web page is scraping is correct, but this is not expected,

bcoz some of the tags are ending with text `conditions` and next tag is starting text with `travels` so that's why it's coming like `conditionstravel`

here i'm willing **scrape** the web page by one by one tags and make it as a web_page_data_list
so is there any way to **scrape** all tags texts with separate state like above

and the problem is we can't give specific dictionary words for this
is that possible with beautiful soup or any other package will help to extract this properly.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `separator=' '` parameter in `.get_text()` method. Also you can supply `strip=True` to strip whitespace characters automatically of every separated word.

For example:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div>Hello<span>World</span></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
web_page=soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
print(web_page.lower())
print(bs4.__version__)
```

Prints:

```
hello world
4.9.1
```

Comment: hi, thankz for the replay,  it's showing me "Unexpected argument" for the seperator='' any idea why it's showing like this , the soup variable is bs4.BeautifulSoup class varable is that work with seperator.? any code changes needed.?

Comment: @VishalVijayan You have typo...it's not `sepErator=`, it's `separator=`

Comment: sry for the mistake on my replay ,but it's not spelling mistake on my code , i just copied from the code u given it's showing strip=true is ok but not able to give separator=' '

Comment: i'm using bs4 version is 4.9.1 and ide is pycharm any code changes with version

Comment: @VishalVijayan Try the code I posted in my updated answer.

Comment: ya it's working as u said but no idea why it's showing on my IDE unexpected argument separator=' '
u r code is working but it's showing same think on my code , i'm updating my full code

Comment: ya i just got the expected output ,but still it's showing me in highlighted color unexpected argument on separator=' ' , but getting the result ,  Thankz for the support